# Поиск по нескольким параметрам RedBeanPhp

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Возможно ли осуществлять поиск по БД при помощи RedBeanPHP по нескольким параметрам? Что-то вроде такого:

```
$test = R::find('pmessages', 'sender = ?, addresser = ?', [$sender, $addresser]);
```

(так не работает)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен `R::find()`

```
$beans=R::find("books","active=? AND id=?",array(1,1));
```

Узнайте больше о R :: find

https://redbeanphp.com/manual3_0/index.php?p=/manual3_0/finding_beans